# Converting a shp file to a list of latitudes and longitudes

Tags: shapefile, gml, latitude-longitude

I have a shp file with the latitudes and longitudes for the boundaries for various geographic regions.  I'd like to convert the shp file into lists of just latitudes and longitudes for the regions.  I'll then use these lists in my program to determine which region a specific point resides in.  Is there a quick way to do this conversion or will I have to read up on the APIs?  Even converting the shp file into GML would be a help as I could easily access that programmatically.

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/index.html will convert shp to gml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Python shapefile library [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/)

```
>>> import shapefile
>>> sf = shapefile.Reader("shapefiles/blockgroups")
>>> shapes = sf.shapes()
>>> # Read the bounding box from the 4th shape
>>> shapes[3].bbox
[-122.485792, 37.786931000000003, -122.446285, 37.811019000000002]
>>>#  Read the 8th point in the 4th shape
>>> shapes[3].points[7]
[-122.471063, 37.787402999999998]
```

i hope it helps you....